# How to display the results of jquery in a table in html

Tags: jquery

I am developing a shopping cart. So far I have displayed all the product details purchased by a user in the form of a table. The Quantity field is given as drop down list. When the user changes the quantity, corresponding price has to change. I am using jQuery. I am calling a jQuery function and calculating the price. But I don't know how to display the result on the appropriate column. This is my jQuery code.

```
function get_price(val, price, cnt) {
    var price1 = val * price;
    $('#priceDisplay' + cnt).html(price1);
    return false;
}
```

Here `cnt` is the row id. `Val` is the value of the selected quantity and price is the base price of that particular product. Now I am trying to display it in the correct position in my html table. The code for the html table is provided below.

```
foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):

$cnt++;
 ?>   <tr>

        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
       <td align="center">
       <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='qty<?php echo $cnt;?>' onChange="get_price(this.value,<?php echo $ar['Price']?>,<?php echo $cnt;?>)">
       <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
               $y="";
               if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                $y="selected";
                }
                echo "<option ";
                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";


            } ?>

       </select>
       </td>

        <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>

         <td name="price"><span id="priceDisplay<?php echo $cnt;?>"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>

        <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='price' id="pprice" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">
```

****EDIT****
THIS IS JUST WHAT I HAVE EDITED IN THE FIDDLE.PLEASE LOOK IT.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Prize</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select class="quant">
            <options>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </options>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td> <span id="val1"></span>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select class="quant">
            <options>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </options>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td> <span id="val2"></span>

    </td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
```

HERE I need to get the span id for particular row.The row is generated dynamically.How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#priceDisplay' + cnt, $(this).parents('tr')).html(price1);
```

Similar [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/36bqR/)

Comment: Hi the problem is that, priceDisplay is not a unique id.<span id="priceDisplay<?php echo $cnt;?> This is my id.Each time id changes as the for each loop continues.Then only i will get the id corresponding to each product.That is priceDisplay1,priceDisplay2,etc will be my id.

Comment: Thank you for your code.But it is not working!What will I do? Is there any other method?

Comment: @user2934937: It should work. I tried it with similar code, check the fiddle.